# scala.MatchError: null while conversion to JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have an app on a base of Play! Framework. There are next classes

```
package models

sealed trait Role

object Role {

  case object Administrator extends Role
  case object Accountant extends Role
  case object Cashier extends Role
  case object Repairman extends Role

  implicit def Role2Int(role: Role): Int = {
    role match {
      case Administrator => 1
      case Accountant => 2
      case Cashier => 4
      case Repairman => 8
      case _ => throw new NotImplementedError(s"Conversion from $role to Int is not supported yet.")
    }
  }

  implicit def Int2Role(i: Int): Role = {
    i match {
      case 1 => Administrator
      case 2 => Accountant
      case 4 => Cashier
      case 8 => Repairman
      case _ => throw new NotImplementedError(s"Not supported role value.")
    }
  }
}

case class User(
  id: Long,
  lastName: String,
  firstName: String,
  middleName: Option[String],
  role: Role,
  creationDate: Date,
  editDate: Option[Date],
  creatorId: Long,
  editorId: Option[Long]
)
```

What I need is to serialize an instance of User type to JSON. To do it with standart play's json-serializer I have to implement a writer.

> Btw: it's strange that one have to write so many lines of code to get
>   a result in such a simple case (the same for the reader). May be there
>   is better solution?

Ok, the writer is done. But when I try the serialization

```
import java.sql.Date

import models.Role.Accountant
import models._
import play.api.libs.json.{Writes, Json}

implicit val userWrites = new Writes[User] {
  def writes(user: User) = Json.obj(
    "id" -> user.id,
    "lastName" -> user.lastName,
    "firstName" -> user.firstName,
    "middleName" -> user.middleName,
    "role" -> Role.Role2Int(user.role),
    "creationDate" -> user.creationDate,
    "editDate" -> user.editDate,
    "creatorId" -> user.creatorId,
    "editorId" -> user.editorId
  )
}

val user = User(1, "Smith", "John", null, Accountant, new Date(System.nanoTime()), null, 0, null)

Json.toJson(user)
```

I get

```
scala.MatchError: null
    at play.api.libs.json.DefaultWrites$$anon$7.writes(app.sc2.tmp:180)
    at play.api.libs.json.DefaultWrites$$anon$7.writes(app.sc2.tmp:178)
    at play.api.libs.json.Json$.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper(app.sc2.tmp:139)
    at #worksheet#.$anon$1.writes(app.sc2.tmp:12)
    at #worksheet#.$anon$1.writes(app.sc2.tmp:7)
    at play.api.libs.json.Json$.toJson(app.sc2.tmp:104)
    at #worksheet#.get$$instance$$res1(app.sc2.tmp:25)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(app.sc2.tmp:49)
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `null` where you should be using `None`?

Comment: @m-z Because I came from .Net :) Thank you! You can answer the question, I'll accept.

Comment: There is a [good post about nothing](http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/08/20/a-post-about-nothing/) that explains differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
val user = User(1, "Smith", "John", null, Accountant, new Date(System.nanoTime()), null, 0, null)
```

should be:

```
val user = User(1, "Smith", "John", None, Accountant, new Date(System.nanoTime()), None, 0, None)
```

As stated in the comment above, change null to None.